# Count(1) Equivalent in Scala From SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, scala, impala

I am trying to create a data frame using scala methods from a sql expression that has a join where the join is a subquery. The query goes something like:

```
SELECT prod.*,
       x.product
FROM productList prod
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id,
                       product,
                       product_code,
                       Count(1) AS product_count, 
                       ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, Count(1) DESC) as prodct_rank 
                FROM productList GROUPBY product_id, product, product_code) x ON prod.product = x.product
                                                                             AND prod.product_id = x.product_id
WHERE product_rank = 1
```

I had tried to convert the query to:

```
      val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("product_id", "product").orderBy("Count(1)")

      val prod_query_df = prod_query.as("prod").
        join((prod_query.as("x").
          select(
            col("x.product_id"),
            col("x.product"),
            col("x.product_code"),
            Count(Literal(1)).as("product_count"),
            row_number.over(windowSpec).desc().as("product_rank")
          ).
          groupby(
            col("x.month_id"),
            col("x.product"),
            col("x.product_id")
          )).as("x"), col("prod.product") === col("x.product") && col("prod.product_id") === col("x.product_id"), "Left").
        filter(col("x.product_rank") === 1).
        select(
          col("prod.*"),
          col("x.product_code")
        )
```

I expected that for the Count(Literal(1)).as("product_count") to take place of the 'Count(1) AS product_count', but this overloads the 'select' scala method. I also am uncertain if my string 'Count(1)' in my windowSpec will provide the expected results.

I also tried searching for similar problems, but most relate to Count(*) and I am unable to find a way to turn it into something similar of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Count("*").as("product_count")
```

and adjust your windowsSpec to reference the `product_count`

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("product_id", "product").orderBy("product_count")
```